# Get Primary Key of Marker Clicked in Google Map in Android Development

Tags: android, google-maps

Help Needed.
I have stored marker locations in an sqlite database in an android application in this way

1. Primary Key
2. Latitude
3. Longitude
4. Zoom

I want to compare all stored locations with my current location at regular intervals and want to delete any marked location whenever I want to remove and want to get primary key of clicked marker.
Can anyone help me how to perform these operations by providing source code for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can get you primary key by this query

var latitude,longitude;
   String query = "SELECT PrimaryKey FROM YourTable WHERE Latitude='"+latitude+"' AND Longitude='"+longitude+"';

then you can use this one to delete your pin from the map,

Comment: i don't know how to execute the query i am using Content Providers and Uri

Comment: can you explain a little bit more so that i can understand

Comment: Sure,  but provide the full detail, Which database are you using,

Comment: SQ-lite database using content providers

Comment: if you tell me your facebook or skype id we can conversate easily